# set author name for a forked and changed source code

Tags: gpl

Here is the Makefile I found on the internet for using rf24 on raspberrypi:

```
#############################################################################
#
# Makefile for librf24 examples on Raspberry Pi
#
# License: GPL (General Public License)
# Author:  gnulnulf <arco@appeltaart.mine.nu>
# Date:    2013/02/07 (version 1.0)
#
# Description:
# ------------
# use make all and make install to install the examples
# You can change the install directory by editing the prefix line
#
prefix := /usr/local

# The recommended compiler flags for the Raspberry Pi
CCFLAGS=-Ofast -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s
#CCFLAGS=

# define all programs
PROGRAMS = rpi-hub scanner

SOURCES = ${PROGRAMS:=.cpp}

all: ${PROGRAMS}

${PROGRAMS}: ${SOURCES}
g++ ${CCFLAGS} -Wall -I../ -lrf24-bcm $@.cpp -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAMS)

install: all
    test -d $(prefix) || mkdir $(prefix)
    test -d $(prefix)/bin || mkdir $(prefix)/bin
    for prog in $(PROGRAMS); do \
      install -m 0755 $$prog $(prefix)/bin; \
    done

.PHONY: install
```

but this make file is not working with raspberrypi 2, and I want to write a code for raspberry pi 2 and find this make file useful, so I changed compiler flag in line 17 from `-march=armv6zk` to `-march=armv7-a` to work with raspberrypi 2.

now if I want to publish this code on GitHub, should I change author`s name to my name or I should keep author`s name or something else?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I edited my question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your name to the actual author's name as a contributor for files you've made code changes to. For anything you didn't change, you aren't the author - you would be taking credit for somebody else's work if you change the author's name to your own. If an employer or potential contributor sees that, it will raise some big questions about your ethics.